# Cannot refrence silverlight 5 class library in normal class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight-5.0

I created a normal class library , and tried to add a silverlght 5 class library it gave warning it's have the same core

also I cannot find entityframework file (edmx) item to add to silverlight 5 , it's multi projects

Answer (score 1):

C# is supported in both Silverlight & .NET

But you can not add reference .net assembly to Silverlight project and vice versa

Because they have their own runtimes, with their specifics and abilities.

You can't add reference entity framework dll to Silverlight project, because Silverlight has no System.Data dll.

You can not add reference System.Data.dll to Silverlight project, because it does not support sql server native drivers.

Try using Portable class libraries & WCF or WCF Data service.

Let me know if any other information is needed.

Good luck

Comment: yes that what I did I separated the EF and used t4 model for classes , but what about the ef entities how to add it

Comment: @AMH You get copies of your entities auto-generated using the EF model as a template if you use RIA Services, which is the most typical way of doing it. If you do it that way, you do not reference any common libraries from the Silverlight projects and the non-Silverlight projects.